# Как спарсить ячейки при условии

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как указать границу регулярками в `php`.
Необходимо спарсить `12` ячеек начиная со слова `bet365`.

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="95%" align="center" border="0" class="oddstable">
  <tbody>
    <tr align="center" class="scoretitle">
      <td height="25" colspan="16">[International Club Friendly]&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <script>
          showDate(2019, 01 - 1, 16, 00, 00, 00);
        </script>01-16 02:00&nbsp;&nbsp;Zamora Barinas(H)&nbsp;
        <font color="yellow">VS</font> &nbsp; Deportivo Metropolitano&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:dataFeedBack(2,1657616)" style="color:blue;">[Data Feedback]</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="Leaguestitle" height="25">
      <td width="15%" rowspan="2"><b>Company</b></td>
      <td colspan="5"><b>1x2 Odds</b></td>
      <td rowspan="15" width="2%" class="b1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="4"><b>Handicap Odds</b></td>
      <td rowspan="15" width="2%" class="b1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="4"><b>Over/Under Odds</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="Leaguestitle" height="25">
      <td>HW</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>AW</td>
      <td>Return</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Home</td>
      <td>Odds</td>
      <td>Away</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Over</td>
      <td>Odds</td>
      <td>Under</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="b1">
      <td width="12%" height="25">Sbobet
        <font color="red">Live</font>
      </td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="5%"></td>
      <td width="6%">0.75<br><span class="">0.75</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.5/1<br><span class="">0.5/1</span></td>
      <td width="6%">1.05<br><span class="">1.05</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/31_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/1_31_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">0.75<br><span class="">0.75</span></td>
      <td width="6%">2/2.5<br><span class="">2/2.5</span></td>
      <td width="6%">1.05<br><span class="">1.05</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/31_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/3_31_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="b2">
      <td width="12%" height="25">12bet
        <font color="red">Live</font>
      </td>
      <td width="7%">1.51<br><span class="">1.51</span></td>
      <td width="7%">3.65<br><span class="">3.65</span></td>
      <td width="7%">5.40<br><span class="">5.40</span></td>
      <td width="7%">89.2%</td>
      <td width="5%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/24_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/5_24_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">1.02<br><span class="">1.02</span></td>
      <td width="6%">1<br><span class="">1</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.78<br><span class="">0.78</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/24_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/1_24_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">1.04<br><span class="">1.04</span></td>
      <td width="6%">2.5<br><span class="">2.5</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.76<br><span class="">0.76</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/24_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/3_24_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="b1">
      <td width="12%" height="25">188bet
        <font color="red">Live</font>
      </td>
      <td width="7%">1.48<br><span class="up">1.57</span></td>
      <td width="7%">3.75<br><span class="up">3.85</span></td>
      <td width="7%">4.75<br><span class="down">4.45</span></td>
      <td width="7%">89.2%</td>
      <td width="5%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/23_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/5_23_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">0.91<br><span class="up">1.08</span></td>
      <td width="6%">1<br><span class="">1</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.79<br><span class="down">0.76</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/23_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/1_23_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">0.81<br><span class="up">0.98</span></td>
      <td width="6%">2.5<br><span class="">2.5</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.89<br><span class="down">0.84</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/23_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/3_23_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="b2">
      <td width="12%" height="25">10BET
        <font color="red">Live</font>
      </td>
      <td width="7%">1.58<br><span class="down">1.55</span></td>
      <td width="7%">3.70<br><span class="down">3.55</span></td>
      <td width="7%">5.10<br><span class="up">5.40</span></td>
      <td width="7%">89.9%</td>
      <td width="5%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/22_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/5_22_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">0.78<br><span class="">0.78</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.5/1<br><span class="">0.5/1</span></td>
      <td width="6%">1.04<br><span class="">1.04</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/22_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/1_22_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">0.99<br><span class="">0.99</span></td>
      <td width="6%">2.5<br><span class="">2.5</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.83<br><span class="">0.83</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/22_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/3_22_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="b1">
      <td width="12%" height="25">M88
        <font color="red">Live</font>
      </td>
      <td width="7%">1.52<br><span class="">1.52</span></td>
      <td width="7%">3.65<br><span class="">3.65</span></td>
      <td width="7%">5.40<br><span class="">5.40</span></td>
      <td width="7%">89.5%</td>
      <td width="5%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/17_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/5_17_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">1.02<br><span class="">1.02</span></td>
      <td width="6%">1<br><span class="">1</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.78<br><span class="">0.78</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/17_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/1_17_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">1.04<br><span class="">1.04</span></td>
      <td width="6%">2.5<br><span class="">2.5</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.76<br><span class="">0.76</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/17_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/3_17_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="b2">
      <td width="12%" height="25">Vcbet</td>
      <td width="7%">1.50<br><span class="up">1.53</span></td>
      <td width="7%">3.75<br><span class="down">3.60</span></td>
      <td width="7%">5.40<br><span class="down">5.25</span></td>
      <td width="7%">89.1%</td>
      <td width="5%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/14_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/5_14_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">0.97<br><span class="up">1.05</span></td>
      <td width="6%">1<br><span class="">1</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.84<br><span class="down">0.77</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/14_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/1_14_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">0.83<br><span class="up">0.92</span></td>
      <td width="6%">2.5<br><span class="">2.5</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.91<br><span class="down">0.80</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/14_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/3_14_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="b1">
      <td width="12%" height="25">Easybet</td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="5%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="b2">
      <td width="12%" height="25">Bet365
        <font color="red">Live</font>
      </td>
      <td width="7%">1.57<br><span class="">1.57</span></td>
      <td width="7%">3.60<br><span class="">3.60</span></td>
      <td width="7%">5.50<br><span class="">5.50</span></td>
      <td width="7%">91.2%</td>
      <td width="5%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/8_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/5_8_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">1.05<br><span class="down">0.77</span></td>
      <td width="6%">1<br><span class="down">0.5/1</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.75<br><span class="up">1.02</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/8_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/1_8_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">1.00<br><span class="down">0.97</span></td>
      <td width="6%">2.5<br><span class="">2.5</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.80<br><span class="up">0.82</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/8_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/3_8_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="b1">
      <td width="12%" height="25">Ladbrokes</td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="5%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="b2">
      <td width="12%" height="25">Crown
        <font color="red">Live</font>
      </td>
      <td width="7%">1.48<br><span class="up">1.57</span></td>
      <td width="7%">3.75<br><span class="up">3.85</span></td>
      <td width="7%">4.75<br><span class="down">4.45</span></td>
      <td width="7%">89.2%</td>
      <td width="5%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/3_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/5_3_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">0.90<br><span class="up">1.07</span></td>
      <td width="6%">1<br><span class="">1</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.80<br><span class="down">0.75</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/3_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/1_3_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">0.80<br><span class="up">1.00</span></td>
      <td width="6%">2.5<br><span class="">2.5</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.90<br><span class="down">0.80</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/3_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/3_3_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="b1">
      <td width="12%" height="25">Macauslot</td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="7%"></td>
      <td width="5%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
      <td width="6%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" class="b2">
      <td width="12%" height="25">18Bet
        <font color="red">Live</font>
      </td>
      <td width="7%">1.48<br><span class="up">1.57</span></td>
      <td width="7%">3.80<br><span class="up">3.90</span></td>
      <td width="7%">4.80<br><span class="down">4.50</span></td>
      <td width="7%">89.6%</td>
      <td width="5%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/42_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/5_42_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">0.91<br><span class="up">1.08</span></td>
      <td width="6%">1<br><span class="">1</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.81<br><span class="down">0.76</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/42_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/1_42_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="6%">0.81<br><span class="up">1.00</span></td>
      <td width="6%">2.5<br><span class="">2.5</span></td>
      <td width="6%">0.91<br><span class="down">0.83</span></td>
      <td width="6%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/42_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="3in1 Runningball"><img src="/images/t1.gif"></a>
              </td>
              <td style="cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="http://data.nowgoal.com/oddshistory/3_42_1657616.html" target="_blank" title="Historical Odds Stats"><img src="/images/ss.gif"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Парсить HTML с помощью регулярок не самый удобный способ. Есть специальные парсеры XML/HTML документов и лучше использовать их.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$tds = $xpath->query('(//*[contains(text(),"Bet365")])[1]/../*'); // все потомки родителя элемента содержащего текст Bet365
foreach ($tds as $td) {
    echo trim($td->textContent) . "\n";
}
```

Вот, например, как можно использовать [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Самое интересное тут это [XPath](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), который позволяет найти элементы по довольно сложному условию:

- `//*` -- любой элемент
- `[contains(text(),"Bet365")]` -- содержащий текст Bet365
- `(...)[1]` -- первый найденный (в XPath нумерация начинается с единицы)
- `/..` -- его родитель
- `/*` -- все вложенные элементы

Соответственно мы получаем все `td` в `tr`, в котором есть `td` с Bet365!

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php
Разбей по `tr`
Например:

```
explode('<tr', <tbody... )
```

и при помощи http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php 
взять нужный срез массива.

Comment: а "bet365" всегда на одном мести будет или таблица динамичная и количество полей будет меняться? Если таблица статичная то имеет смысл просто разбить по tr и взять срез массива